# Average of a student using prolog

Tags: prolog

I know this looks a bit silly, but I'm trying to find the average of a given student using Prolog, here's my piece of code:

```
score( jason , math101 , 90 ).
score( sami  , math102 , 67 ).
score( smith , phys101 , 82 ).
score( sami  , chem101 , 88 ).

do(X,S,I) :-
  score(X,_,B) ,
  write(B) ,
  S is S+B ,
  I is I+1 ,
  write(I) ,
  fail.

start :-
  read(X) ,
  do(X,0,0)
  .
```

I'm trying to do it using recursion, the problem is that I (stands for index) and S(stands for sum) wont  increment ! what did I do wrong? thanks !

Comment: In Prolog, you can't change a variable within a predicate clause once it's set. So the expression `S is S+B` asked Prolog to provide a value `S` such that `S is S + B` which will always be false (unless `B` is zero).

Answer (score 0):

You code has some problems:

1. Expressions like `S is S+B` don't work in prolog. Once a variable is unified with a term (assigned a value), **it ceases to be variable**: it becomes that with which it was unified. Hence the name *unification*.
2. Your `do/3` predicate will always fail. It looks like you are forcing backtracking via `fail/0` and expecting your counters to be incremented as you go. Prolog doesn't work like that: As you backtrack, unification is undone, so even if you'd managed to increment your `S` and `B` variables, the increment would have been rolled back as you backtracked through it.
3. You are invoking your `do/3` predicate with `S` and `B` already unified to a value (0). So your `is/2` expressions are the exact equivalent of this:

   ```
   0 is 0+B , % S is S+B ,
   0 is 0+1 , % I is I+1 ,
   ```

You can see how that won't work.

What you need to do is collect the scores for each student as a list. Since you can only get them one at a time via backtracking, building that list is a little difficult. If you tried to build that list via recursion, on each recursion you find yourself starting over from ground zero. Conveniently, [Prolog offers a set of predicates for collecting data from all solutions to a goal as a list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions):

- `setof/3` finds the *set* of all solutions to a goal, presenting them as a list.
- `findall/3` finds the *bag* of all solutions to a goal, presenting them as a list.
- `bagof/3` finds the *bag* of all solutions to a goal, presenting them as a list.

Notes: `findall/3` and `bagof/3` are similar but different: to quote the docs, "`findall/3` is equivalent to `bagof/3` with all free variables bound with the existential operator `^`". You'll probably need to play with it a bit to grok just what that means. The difference between *set* and *bag* is that by definition, *sets* are unique and have no duplicates. *Bags*, on the other hand are not necessarily unique and may contain duplicates.

At any rate, you're interested in `bagof/3`.

The first thing to do is *decompose* your problem into simple pieces. The first thing you need to do is compute the average score for a single student. to do that you need:

- The student's name,
- The list of individual scores for that student, and
- a way to compute the arithmetic mean from a list of numbers.

So, let's tackle each of this in turn. The 1st two problems are solved with `bagof/3`. This:

```
bagof(Score,score(Student,_,Score),Scores) .
```

will find the list of scores for a student, unifying `Student` with the student's name and `Scores` with the list of individual scores. On backtracking it will successively do the same for all students.

That takes care of the first two simple problems. The 3rd problem isn't much more difficult. Here we will introduce two concepts that are integral to prolog: *recursion* and the use of *accumulators* to develop a value. we have to do this because as noted, in Prolog, all variables are local and can only be assigned a value once. So to develop a value, we have to recursively carry the state around that we need. A common idiom is the use of *helper predicates* that do all the work and are invoked by the "public" predicate that the user actually uses.

We can compute the arithmetic mean of a list of numbers like this:

```
compute_mean( Ns, M ) :-         % to compute the mean of a list of numbers,
  compute_mean( Ns , 0 , 0 , M ) % - just invoke the helper with the counters seeded as zero.
  .                              % Also easy!

compute_mean( [] , S , N , M ) :-     % if the source list is exhausted,
  N > 0 ,                             % - and we have a non-zero N (division by zero being undefined),
  M is float(S) / float(N)            % - compute the arithmetic mean, casting both counters to floats
  .                                   % otherwise...
compute_mean( [X|Xs] , S , N , M ) :- % if the source list isn't yet exhausted,
  S1 is S+X ,                         % - add the data point to the running total,
  N1 is N+1 ,                         % - increment the count of data points,
  compute_mean(Xs,S1,N1,M)            % - and recurse down on the tail of the list.
  .                                   % Easy!
```

That's all we need to compute the average score for a student, and on backtracking, successively do so for *all* students. Just put the two things together:

```
mean_score( Student , Mean ) :-                     % to compute the mean score for a student,
  bagof( Mean , score(Student,_,Score) , Scores ) , % - get the bag of the scores for the student
  compute_mean( Scores , Mean )                     % - and then compute the mean score
  .                                                 % Easy!
```

Once you have that, you could then just say something like this:

```
list_mean_scores_for_all_students :-
  mean_score(Student,Mean) ,
  write( Student:Mean) , nl ,
  fail .
list_mean_scores_for_all_students .
```

The problem with the above is that `list_mean_scores_for_all_students/0` will *always* succeed, even if something untowards happened. So, you might want to use `findall/3` to collect them all at once and then process them.
Then we can say:

```
list_mean_scores_for_all_students :-
  findall( Student:Mean , mean_score(Student,Mean) , Results ) ,
  log_results(Results)
  .

log_results( [] ) .
log_results( [S:M|Xs] ) :-
  write(S:M),nl ,
  log_results(Xs)
  .
```

If something fails, `list_means_scores_for_all_students/0` will fail.